# Convert numpy.where to Linq

Tags: python, c#, numpy, linq

I have a `function` in `python` that uses `numpy.where`:

```
def f(sT, price, p):
       return np.where(sT > price, sT - price, 0) – p
```

where `sT` is a `list` of `double`

I would like to convert this to a `C# Linq`. I can filter the list, but I am not sure how to implement the rest of the python function:

```
public static List<double> CallPayoff(List<double> sT, double price, double p)
 {
        List<double> retVal = new List<double>();

        var prices = stockPricesList.Where(x => x > price); // What else goes in here?

        foreach (var p in prices)
            Debug.WriteLine(p.ToString());

        return retVal;
}
```

Comment: You basically said "here's some Python, plz convert it to C#" - even if people want to be a code translation service, you kinda rather restricted it to people who know py and c#.. and that's unnecessary if only you'd put a bit more into the question, along the lines of "if I had an array of ints in c#, how would I find the average of only the positive ones" or similar ie don't sit and hope someone knows both languages, just explain what you need (ie what the Python does) and increase your target audience (ie even C# only people will be able to answer it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your particular case, the name "where" is misleading.

In Python it is used to transform data based on a condition, so it is some sort of specialized projection, while in Linq/C# it is a filtering operation.

Use the Linq general purpose projection operation: "Select", which you can customize to use a condition, with a simple ternary ?: operator.

In Python, assuming St is a one dimensional array:

```py
np.where(sT > price, sT - price, 0)
```

would be equivalent to the following in C#:

```cs
stockPricesList
    .Select(x => x > price ? x - price : 0);
```